# How to read messages from a rabbitmq queue running in a local docker container

Tags: java, docker, networking, rabbitmq, amqp

I am running rabbitmq in my local mac in docker container. I accessed it through the GUI (at port 15672) in browser and created a queue, exchange and published some messages in the queue. I am trying to write a java application which can read the messages from the queue and print it in the console but I am running in to this error.

```
rjashnani-ltm:rabbitmq rjashnani$ java -cp .:amqp-client-5.7.1.jar:slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar:slf4j-simple-1.7.26.jar Recv
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
```

I created docker container using this command

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit2 -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

Here is my Java application code

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.DeliverCallback;

public class Recv {

    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "test-queue";

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        factory.setPort(5762);
        factory.setUsername("guest");
        factory.setPassword("guest");
        factory.setVirtualHost("/");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
        System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

        DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
            String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
        };
        channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> { });
    }
}
```

Comment: `factory.setPort(5762);` and you are forwarding `5672` port.

Comment: @michalk No. I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: You have a typo. Your connection factory creates connections for port `5762` but you are publishing `5672` to your host in your `docker run` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run -it --rm --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

Running docker with `-it` argument, resolved the issue.